# Return a unique array of values from array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have an array `@contacts` of hashes, each of which has the following keys:

```
:full_name
:city
:state
:email
```

How would I iterate through the array to return the `:city` values uniquely? Below is my best attempt

```
@contacts.uniq {|hash| hash[:city]}
```

Comment: if this is rails, you could do it at the db layer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@contacts.map { |k| k[:city] }.uniq
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Does this mean that any .method added to the block of code is executed when whatever conditions inside that block return a value/true?

Comment: No, it's equivalent to `(t = @contacts.map { |k| k[:city] }; t.uniq)`